# Submit data to two different SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath-rules

I am new to SharePoint and Infopath 2010, and i have been told to create a module to record bills payment. But i have an issue with making the bill reference field, an extensible field to allow one payment to solve many bills.

'1' payment <---> 'n' bills

So i have two lists the 1st named 'Payments' and the 2nd 'Bills', the issue is how to submit information about a payment to the first list, and bills references to the second list.

### Thank you

Edited : 
I found a way using qDabra Rules, but i'm having the following error :
Action: SubmitToSharePointList. 
Arguments: 
    submit: submitComp 
    mapping: compMapping 
    id: /my:mesChamps/my:ID .

Details: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, 
Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable..

Stack: 
    à Qdabra.Tools.RulesLibrary.SubmitToSharePointList.Execute() 
    à Qdabra.Tools.RulesLibrary.CommandStarter.Run() 
    à Qdabra.Tools.RulesLibrary.Commands.RunCommand(Commands command)
     à Qdabra.Tools.RulesLibrary.Commands.ExecuteCommand()

Comment: Since you have one or more bills, save the form in the form library  and then an event reciever will save the data to the two lists. Wiil this answer suffice you?   http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-submit-items-rows-repeating-table-infopath-sharepoint-list.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i only want to save the bill reference !

Comment: You save it temporarily. I suggest you add qdabra to the tags. Also, you can ask qdabra for the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by saving the form as an InfoPath 2010 form, because I were working with SharePoint 2010 (version 14) and SharePoint 2013 (version 15)